# DUKPT - Sample data other then in X9.24

Tags: cryptography, key-management, key-generation

I wrote some code that does PIN encryption/decryption according to rules in X9.24.
It works great with examples provided in ANSI doc, but doesn't work with actual device from the client.

Where can I find more sample data to run my code through, to make sure that my code is correct?

Is it possible that some device manufacturers do not follow ANSI to a T?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's always possible for a device manufacturer to not follow the specification.  There was a question on Stackoverflow asking how to implement the standard ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071474/how-to-implement-ans-x9-24-dukpt-using-java ) and they pointed to jPos: http://www.jpos.org/.  It appears to contain test data.

Answer (score 1):

Our vendor gave us sample code that works with their equipment. I was a little surprised to notice they left out a step from the `ANSI 9.24-1` standard. I read though that document hundreds of times, and I can't believe I missed it saying that it was optional, but I had to decrypt what they were sending so I left the step out, and we are decrypting just fine.

Specifically, on page 49 of `ANS X9.24-1:2009`, it says:

> 4) `XOR` the Key Register with hexadecimal `“0000 0000 0000 00FF 0000
>   0000 0000 00FF”`. (This will produce a variant of the key.)

Our new vendor left this out. Interestingly, our old vendor left it in. I don’t make the rules, I just write code that works.